# How do I use use an MDX set for a calculated member in Excel?

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx, pivot-table

I'm using Excel 2013 and SSAS 2014. I'm trying to group multiple members together for a report, based on the report context.

I'm trying to accomplish this by creating a custom member that contains all of the members I want to group. If I hard-code the member, it works fine, but using MDX, it fails.

**This works:**

```
[Terminals].[Terminal].[Terminal 1] + [Terminals].[Terminal].[Terminal 2]
```

**This does not work:**

```
Union([Terminals].[Terminal].[Terminal 1], [Terminals].[Terminal].[Terminal 2])
```

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145493.aspx) for the + operator:

> The + (Union) operator is functionally equivalent to the Union (MDX) function.

However this must not be the case, since substituting the addition sign for the union function does not produce the same result. I cannot find an alternate form of the plus operator in the MDX reference.

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is filter members in a hierarchy by a data-defined rule:

```
Filter(
  [Terminals].[Terminal].Children,
  ClosingPeriod([Date].[By Week].[Date], [Measures].[Days])
)
```

The above function returns a set of Terminals where a record exists on the last day of the period selected in the query. The user may want to either INCLUDE or EXCLUDE these from the report.

How do I use use an MDX set for a calculated member in Excel?

### UPDATE:

Greg's suggestion below works with Filter using the following syntax:

```
Aggregate(
    FILTER(
        NonEmpty([Terminals].[Terminal ID].Members),
        (ClosingPeriod([Date].[By Week].[Date]),[Measures].[Days]) = 1
    )
)
```

Note that **Children** didn't work, but **Members** did.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Is there an error message?

Comment: It gives the all-obscure error message "The function expects a tuple set expression for the 1 argument. A string or numeric expression was used"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are adding the calculated member to the Terminals dimension then this will work:

```
Aggregate(
 Union([Terminals].[Terminal].[Terminal 1], [Terminals].[Terminal].[Terminal 2])
)
```

If you are creating a new calculated measure do this:

```
Aggregate(
 Union([Terminals].[Terminal].[Terminal 1], [Terminals].[Terminal].[Terminal 2])
,[Measures].[Your Other Measure]
)
```

The same pattern can be applied to your more complex Filter() expression.

Comment: HI Greg.. off topic a bit but can I pick your brain please: I've recently found in some slightly more complex scripts with several custom elements which include Aggregate in some of them I need to use Solve_order ... is Aggregate given a special place in the processing order that it is worth being aware of?

Comment: Substituting Filter for Union fails :(

    Aggregate(
 FILTER(
  NonEmpty([Terminals].[Terminal ID].Children),
  (ClosingPeriod([Date].[By Week].[Date]),[Measures].[Days]) = 1
 )
)

Comment: I updated the original post with the progress I made based on your suggestion

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. The problems I'm encountering now are with Excel and constitute a new question being posted. If you get a moment, it would be great if you could explain to my why your solution works: I fear there is something fundamental I'm not understanding. Also, why I must wrap my FILTER in a SET for me to be able to use it in the calculated member

Comment: Glad to help. I wonder if it is an infinite recursion error? [Terminals].[Terminal ID].Children would reference your calculated member Is Active. Maybe the set ensures that set is evaluated before the calculated member? I'm not sure. Hard to know without getting hands on your cube.

Comment: You're probably right. I solved it by using "Members" instead, and it works as expected. Thanks for your help! I'll update my original post.

Comment: Good thought. Yes .Members won't return calculate members. But .AllMembers would. And I believe .Children does.

Comment: Don't you need to change your code to [Terminals].[Terminal ID].[Terminal ID].Members so you don't include the All member in the Is Active total?